# Ubuntu 14.04LTS, Clevo with intel N-7260, cannot connect to home wifi (deauthenticated Reason: 2)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I need you kind help.
I've been using my laptop (a re-badged CLEVO) with Ubuntu 14.04LTS for more than a year now. 
Quite often I have had trouble connecting to some wifi networks (though some others work flawlessly everytime...), but usually turning the wifi off and on again is enough. If I don't do that, then the "waves" indicating the wifi connection will keep on moving (as they do while connecting) for a very long while, and then either fail silently (empty quadrant) or ask for the password again (entering a loop where I'm asked for password every minute or so).

This happen to me again today, on my home wifi, but this time no matter what I do I can't seem to make it work again... It keeps asking me for password (which I made extra-sure is correct). My (android) smartphone could connect without a problem, but my laptop won't...

Here is the result of the wireless-info script (found here : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/master/wireless-info from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108)

[Note: My home wifi is called Freebox-5ECBD0, so I edited out everything related to other surrounding wifis (but since both my smartphone and my windows desktop computer can connect without a problem, I guess this is not important...)]

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 15 Jun 2015 10:53 CEST +0200

Booted last: 15 Jun 2015 10:20 CEST +0200

Script from: 21 May 2015 09:10 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-54-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 26 19:15:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260     [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4062]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

05:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:6500]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1267:0212 Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                189852  0 
mac80211              630728  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19177  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'docker0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'usb0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.145  Bcast:192.168.42.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::34:30ff:fe32:6c04/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5982 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:4986 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5917375 (5.9 MB)  TX bytes:793773 (793.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e8b:fdff:fe81:ae7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2646872 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:824718 (824.7 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

usb0      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       929     1  0 10:20 ?        00:00:02 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: usb0  [Auto Ethernet]     ------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            rndis_host
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'usb0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.42.145
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.42.129

    DNS:             192.168.42.129

- Device: <MAC address> ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:

- Device: eth0     -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0     ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

Wireless Access Points 
Freebox-5ECBD0:  Infra, <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Freebox-5ECBD0]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Freebox-5ECBD0 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Freebox-5ECBD0 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Paris (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

usb0      no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

docker0   no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      3   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
      4   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]>
                Channel:9
                Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Freebox-5ECBD0"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                          6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000001b9764e91f5
                Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
      Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'FreeWifi_secure' [AC2]>
                Channel:9
                Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"FreeWifi_secure"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                          6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000001b9764da1b9
                Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
      Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'FreeWifi' [AC3]>
                Channel:9
                Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                Encryption key:off
                ESSID:"FreeWifi"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 22 Mb/s
                          6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000001b9764e1a4f
                Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-54-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     2ED88DF9FE06B5CF295C51A
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        B3:81:89:C2:17:9B:E6:0A:3B:0C:B0:89:E5:0C:59:B0:0F:98:32:70
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-54-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2CE061809D3601D619ACB8E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        B3:81:89:C2:17:9B:E6:0A:3B:0C:B0:89:E5:0C:59:B0:0F:98:32:70
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-54-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     A45BAACCAD263355629DB7A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        B3:81:89:C2:17:9B:E6:0A:3B:0C:B0:89:E5:0C:59:B0:0F:98:32:70
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-54-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     22618C9A8AD682CBE73FFF2
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        B3:81:89:C2:17:9B:E6:0A:3B:0C:B0:89:E5:0C:59:B0:0F:98:32:70
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b1 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[ 1780.308522] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (Reason: 2)
[ 1788.368676] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]>
[ 1788.370264] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1788.372107] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1788.374658] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1788.386845] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1788.402382] wlan0: associated
[ 1792.396795] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (Reason: 2)
[ 1804.763730] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]>
[ 1804.765230] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1804.767051] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1804.769121] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1804.781455] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1804.805504] wlan0: associated
[ 1808.784536] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (Reason: 2)
[ 1818.006410] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]>
[ 1818.008088] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1818.009930] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1818.011250] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1818.025931] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1818.026949] wlan0: associated
[ 1822.031913] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (Reason: 2)
[ 1834.403075] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]>
[ 1834.404546] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1834.406411] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1834.409182] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1834.430672] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1834.445562] wlan0: associated
[ 1838.439075] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (Reason: 2)
[ 1845.876704] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]>
[ 1845.882305] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1845.884132] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1845.885843] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1845.898506] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1845.925366] wlan0: associated
[ 1849.908091] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (Reason: 2)
[ 1862.281812] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]>
[ 1862.283359] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1862.285197] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1862.287839] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1862.299700] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1862.313496] wlan0: associated
[ 1866.307592] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'Freebox-5ECBD0' [AC1]> (Reason: 2)

########## wireless info END ############
```

That was one long wall of text, I hope you'll find whatever info you need to help me debug that...